# Clone ports from bsd installation to another

Tags: bsd, freebsd

I have a production FreeBSD webserver which I would like to "clone" to create a development/preproduction server.

I've installed a clean FreeBSD server and now I would like to know if there's an easy way to list all the ports installed on the production server, get that list out and input that to the new server, so I can easily install all the same apps and same versions than in the production machine.

We are using:
FreeBSD 7.1
portmaster as a port manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from the `EXAMPLES` section of the `portmaster` man page:

- First, get a list of installed ports:

  ```
  portmaster --list-origins > installed-port-list
  ```
- On your target system, use that list as input to `portmaster`:

  ```
  portmaster `cat installed-port-list`
  ```

Comment: ...although this won't necessarily get you the *same* version of the ports unless the ports tree on your target system matches the installed versions on your production host.

Comment: Interesting... There are some ports tha 'don't exist', so I think that should mean that I don't have that repositories or something like that... I'm trying to find a fix to that now...

Comment: I'm a linux admin and I'm still a bit lost in this :D

Comment: Make sure your ports tree is up-to-date -- or is at least identical to the production system.  It's possible that your installed packages may be out of sync w/r/t the ports tree if some were installed using "pkg_add" (which installs binary packages).

Comment: Are there different port trees like there are repositories in ubuntu? A config file I can check?

Comment: [This](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports.html) is probably the best source of information.  In general, no, there's only one "ports tree", but there are multiple versions of it (e.g., -release, -stable, etc).

Comment: Wonderful, I'll study that.

Comment: @larsks
Why just not tomake a full back up.

Answer (score 0):

you need bash

mkdir -p /usr/local/pkg

cd /usr/local/pkg

for i in `pkg_info |cut -f 1 -d " "` ; do pkg_create -b $i ; done

then, scp the resulting pkgs to the target server and install them by pkg_add *
Then, copy over the /usr/local/etc of the source-server and copy any entries in /etc/rc.conf and related files that seem useful and appropriate.

Comment: Why is `bash` necessary?